# ¿Cómo centrar todos los elementos de un Constraint Layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, constraint-layout

Necesito centrar todos los elementos en un Constraint Layout , antes lo hacia con un Layout (vertical) agregando la propiedad android:gravity="center", pero necesito hacerlo sin Layouts para lograr que se mantengan los elementos en el centro del diseño, existe alguna forma he intentado con otras herramientas de Android Studio como guidelines o cadenas de restricciones pero estas alteran el diseño original.

Este es mi diseño original

[image: Este es mi diseño]

Este es mi código del diseño xml en cual mantengo un margen de 16dp entre los elementos.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/darkGray"
tools:context=".PrivacyActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="Login"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
    
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Contraseña"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button11"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:text="ACCEDER"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada layout_constraint debe tener su valor de esta manera puedes jugar con el espacio de vista. Así quedaría tu código

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/greenFocus"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.337" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColorHint="@color/grisFocus"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.035" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.028" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:text="ACCEDER"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]